# Android Volley Json Request: Parameters not showing

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I'm doing a simple app where all you have to do at this point is press the connect button to ask for a lock request to be granted. If it is granted, then the JSON response appears. This requires an HTTP header( X-API-key) which I pasted into strings.xml. I specified it in the headers. I included the parameters as well. I already tested the URL in postman and it's working fine. Here, an error message appears. As you'll see below, I have two classes: Main Activity and MySingleton. Thank you in advance.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button connect;
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private TextView textResponse;
    private Map<String, String> headers;
    private Map<String, String> mParams;

    String lockUrl = "https://lzx650r9ih.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/p01/lock";


     @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        connect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect_button);
        textResponse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textResponse);

        //press the connect button to request a lock
        connect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, lockUrl, null,
                        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                textResponse.setText("Response: " + response.toString());
                                connect.setText(R.string.Connection_lock);
                                //if the lock is granted then the green button appears
                                mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.bullet_green);
                            }

                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        connect.setText(R.string.Connection_no);
                        //if no connection then the red button appears
                        mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle_red);
                        VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());

                    }

                }) {

                    @Override
                    public Map<String, String> getParams()throws AuthFailureError {
                        HashMap<String, String> mParams = new HashMap<String,String>();
                        mParams.put("nameSpace", "accounting");
                        mParams.put("lockName", "kevin1");
                        mParams.put("durationSeconds", "600");
                        mParams.put("userParam", "Cust-20221");
                        mParams.put("callbackUrl","www.yahoo.com");
                        return mParams;
                    }


                    @Override
                    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        headers.put("x-api-key", getResources().getString(R.string.parse_api_key));
                        return headers;
                    }

                };

                MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
            }
        });
        }}
```

Singleton:

```
public class MySingleton {

    private static MySingleton mInstance;
    private static Context mCtx;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;

    private MySingleton(Context context) {
        mCtx = context;
        requestQueue = getRequestQueue();
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (requestQueue == null) {
            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return requestQueue;
    }

    public static synchronized MySingleton getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new MySingleton(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> request) {
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please paste the error message?

Comment: I'm running it on my phone and the response is: {"err":", statusCode":"....invalid input parameter ...Missing 'lockName' Parameter.

Comment: I think their is a problem with your lockName parameter in server end. Try to POST data from postman REST client before go code.

Comment: Use same key for lockName as you used in your postman request

Comment: I'm using the same key.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this code in **setOnClickListener**

```
String lockUrl = "https://lzx650r9ih.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/p01/lock?nameSpace=accounting&lockName=kevin1qq&durationSeconds=600&userParam=Cust-20221&callbackUrl=www.yahoo.com";

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, lockUrl,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.e("RES  :  ", "RES  IS  " + response);
                    textResponse.setText("Response: " + response.toString());
                    connect.setText(R.string.Connection_lock);
                    //if the lock is granted then the green button appears
                    mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.bullet_green);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    connect.setText(R.string.Connection_no);
                    //if no connection then the red button appears
                    mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle_red);
                    VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("x-api-key", "sOdgqxUJmm6lKAObnI2Dq5JYv6f4NVot9KMiNMWL");
            return headers;
        }
    };

    MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
```

Comment: in your old code 
connect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

Comment: have you replaced your existing code in your connect.setOnClickListener with above code?

Comment: Yes, I have and now I'm getting the 403 error code when I press the button on my phone.

Comment: can you provide x-api-key if possible?

Comment: I'm new to this forum; so I didn't know about this. Yes, let's move this to chat. I'm not allowed to use chat as of yet. api-key:sOdgqxUJmm6lKAObnI2Dq5JYv6f4NVot9KMiNMWL

Comment: we are near to your ans just tell me R.string.parse_api string resource value

to see GO to values>string.xml

Comment: I posted the key above.

Comment: ok please send your postman response screen shot or edit question

Comment: Where can I post my screenshot?

Comment: forget it do a thing upload a screen shot in your drive google and share link in  comnt

Comment: Same error message. Why did you delete Request.Method.GET? In Postman, GET works and POST doesn't.

Comment: in your provided screen shot it used get method so, that's why i removed it( if i not write Request.Method.GET then by default it will pass req by using GET method).

this is working using get method if you want POST method then u need to modify service as per that.

Comment: ND1010, thanks. It works. I forgot to mention that I already tried putting params in the url. Why doesn't it work when you put them in the params method?

Comment: Its may be a server side issue or may be other.
By d way you will click on right mark behind my answer if you like my efferents LOL.

Comment: ND1010, my clicks aren't recorded in the public profile because I don't enough reputation points. You should get private feedback.